# How to stick the header to the top of the screen with react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, navbar

I'm pretty new to building websites and none of the solutions I've found online have worked. I just want to keep the navbar at the top of the screen at all times.

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './Home'
import About from './About'
import Staking from './Staking'
import Mint from './Mint'
import Layout from './Layout'
import Roadmap from './Roadmap'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="staking" element={<Staking />} />
            <Route path="mint" element={<Mint />} />
            <Route path="roadmap" element={<Roadmap/>} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What navbar are you referring to? Can you edit your post to include all relevant code you are working with? See [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese When I try to add more code it doesn't let me save as there is too much code, sorry I'm new to all this.

Comment: Do you happen to have this code available in a public repo or can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?